# SVN Post-Commit exe failed to start

Tags: vb.net, windows, svn, post-commit-hook

I've created a VB.Net exe which pulls information from my teams SVN Repository in order to post that information on a channel on our slack page.  I've named the exe post-commit.exe and placed it in the hooks folder within our SVN repository (which is contained within a sever that we access through a mapped network drive) in place of the post-commit.tmpl file.  When I commit to our repository via TortoiseSvn I end up getting a message stating "Failed to Start 'Path of post commit exe' hook".

Now if I go into the folder and run the exe manually it runs as epxected.  I've done a test for this on my local documents folder by creating a completely new repository and it managed to run the post-commit exe on the commit.  Does anyone know why the post-commit is not running?  Is it permission related as I've attempted to give the exe permissions for all ussers to read and execute the exe.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but I want to make sure: what system does your server run on? Is it also a Windows system? When you run your .exe manually, are you running it on your computer or on the server?

Comment: Hey there, the server is also a Windows server.  I am running the exe manually on my computer.  I haven't tried running it on the server so might give that a go.